# how to use ajax in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am making a like button to like the post.

I want to show the counter of likes without the page being reloaded. I am very new to ajax.

Can someone please tell me the the script and the function and the view.

Comment: This goes beyond the scope of what we help with here. We'll help you if you get stuck, but we won't write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have created small function which helps me every time I want to send ajax.

```
    function ajaxCall(url, data, method = "post") {
        data._token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: method,
            data: data
        }).done(function(resp) {
            //Do Your Code
        }).fail(function (resp) {
            //Do Fail Code
        });
    }
```

If you want to use ajax post with laravel you should send `_token` with data. If it's get method than you can not pass `_token` to ajax call... You can create route and try this function out.